# Pass DotNetNuke User Information To PHP Site As Login

Tags: php, authentication, dotnetnuke

I've been using DotNetNuke for my company's main website.  A separate vendor built a tool that we're using to sell our product.  That vendor built it's application on Linux/Apache/MySQL/PHP.  They use the standard forms authentication.

Is it possible to create a link on my dotnetnuke site that passes some user information (e-mail address as username, other text as password - not dotnetnuke password) to the php site to use as a login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. Create a page that will retrieve the data you want from DNN and then send it to the PHP site using WebRequest. See [How to: Send Data Using the WebRequest Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx).

Comment: "Create a page" on the PHP site or DNN?  Does the vendor need to create some sort of endpoint for me to send the data?

Comment: Create the page in your DNN website. The vendor (assuming) runs PHP, all he'd have to do is create a page on his side (that you will post to using WebRequest). The vendor can just do a $_POST['DNNVariablePosted'] to retrieve a posted field's value on his side. There's really nothing special about WebRequest, it just allows you to do a HTTP POST programmatically instead of using a normal <form>.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the IFrame module in DNN?  It has options to include QueryString Parameters with the site you're displaying.  Of course, this approach assumes that your PHP site is expecting the email address, username, and other text you mention as a QueryString.